# How to create a WordPress custom category page

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a category page that displays the category name, its description and thumbnail. Each category should be linked to its posts when we click on any category it should show its posts on next page.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container-wrap">

    <div class="container main-content">

    <div class="container">

                <h1 class="page-header">
                <?php echo category_description(); ?>
                </h1>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#project-link">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/700x400.png" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" width="250" height="180" />
                </a>
                <h3>
                <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $category_id=65 ) ?>">
                <?php echo get_cat_name(65);?>
                </a>
                </h3>
                <p><?php  echo category_description(); ?></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#project-link">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/700x400.png" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" width="250" height="180" />
                </a>
                <h3>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                <?php echo get_cat_name(68);?>
                </a>
                </h3>
                <p><?php  echo category_description(); ?></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#project-link">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/700x400.png" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" width="250" height="180" />
                </a>
                <h3>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                <?php echo get_cat_name(70);?>
                </a>
                </h3>
                <p><?php  echo category_description(); ?></p>
            </div>



            </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#project-link">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/700x400.png" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" width="250" height="180" />
                </a>
                <h3>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                <?php echo get_cat_name(67);?>
                </a>
                </h3>
                <p><?php  echo category_description(); ?></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#project-link">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/700x400.png" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" width="250" height="180" />
                </a>
                <h3>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                <?php echo get_cat_name(71);?>
                </a>
                </h3>
                <p><?php  echo category_description(); ?></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#project-link">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/700x400.png" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" width="250" height="180" />
                </a>
                <h3>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                <?php echo get_cat_name(72);?>
                </a>
                </h3>
                <p><?php  echo category_description(); ?></p>
            </div>



            </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#project-link">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/700x400.png" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" width="250" height="180" />
                </a>
                <h3>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                <?php echo get_cat_name(69);?>
                </a>
                </h3>
                <p><?php  echo category_description(); ?></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#project-link">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/700x400.png" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" width="250" height="180" />
                </a>
                <h3>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                <?php echo get_cat_name(74);?>
                </a>
                </h3>
                <p><?php  echo category_description(); ?></p>
            </div>
+   
            </div>

    </div>

    </div>
    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For custom category page , you have to create a PHP file in your theme root directory with the name of taxonomy-category-slug-here.php. It'll work for you.

```
taxonomy-category-slug-here.php
```